# How correct initialize a class instance using kwargs

Tags: django, python-3.x, keyword-argument

I try to initialize a class with ihertitance structure.
I already read a lot of questions here, but still can't figure out how should I do this.
**My model:**

```
class BaseCrudEntity(models.Model):
    pass
    class Meta:
        abstract = True

class Person(BaseCrudEntity):

    Name = models.CharField(max_length = 255)

def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if args:
            self.Name = args
        super().__init__(self, *args)
        pass
```

And here I call it:

```
p = Person("Test2")
p.save()
```

As a result I have an error:
**int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'Person'**
Here my traceback:
http://dpaste.com/2BJFF38

How should I initialize class instance?

Why in shell I see *None*:

```
>>> from person.models.person import *
>>> p = Person('Tttt')
>>> p
<Person:  Tttt None>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I also just noticed this in your posted code: `super().__init__(self, *args)`... You are not passing your Model's `kwargs` to super() either

Comment: Thanks, I fix it, but it did not solve main problem (with saving an instance)
I suppose it is smth with database id (because I dont know **what else could be integer here**) Does anyone have some ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Kwargs in Python are not called the way you showed in your code. These are "keyword" arguments, so you must provide a keyword arg to init.

However this is Django, your issue is much more simple and the Kwargs are already provided for instantiation with models.

Your class has a `Name` attribute, notice capitalization. Create the object like so and you're good:

```
p = Person(Name="John")
p.save()

# or

Person.create(Name="John")
```

But for reference, using kwargs with your current naming structure, it would be like this:

```
class BaseCrudEntity(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        abstract = True

     def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
         print('in base init')

class Person(BaseCrudEntity):

    Name = models.CharField(max_length = 255)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        name = kwargs.pop('name') 
        self.Name = name
        print(f'{self.Name} before super()')
        super().__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        print(f'{self.Name} was created and is here after super()')


Person(name='John')
```

Here is a nice article explaining the difference between args and kwargs: https://pythontips.com/2013/08/04/args-and-kwargs-in-python-explained/

Comment: Unfortunately this is did not work at all. Instance field Name (p.Name) is empty in your solution. But this does not matter.
My problem is not about args or kwargs (but yes, I did not understand it as expert), my problem is about saving an instance of inherited class.
Could you please clarify, why I see an exeption wrtitten by bold font? And what should I do for solving this?

Comment: Have you run my code directly? I am not in my home right now so I can't run that, but there are no issues with it. I will run it when I get home, but you had a few little things wrong initially as well, read my comment to your post, you'll also see print statements where the issue is. I also don't want to say this because you'd have gotten errors, but just in case, make sure you run migrations

Comment: I mean this is not about the *how* I initialize class. By args, kwargs, or pushing variables directly into init. The result is the same - I got an exception, whent trying to save model

Comment: I comment the arg, kwarg and so on.
I just call p = Person('Test)
where init is
```
def __init__(self, Name = None)
    self.Name = Name
    super().__init__(self, Name)
```
so there is no problem in args. the problem is in the **way how I create instance of a child class**. But I don't know how to fix it. At least yet.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I found here is to call `__init__` of parent class from within the child class **without** using a `super() call`. Somewhy in my exact case the call via super is not working properly, because `p.id` attribute is initialized by `<Person Name>` instead of integer value.

So the working solution is:

```
class BaseCrudEntity(models.Model):
    pass
    class Meta:
        abstract = True

class Person(BaseCrudEntity):

    Name = models.CharField(max_length = 255)

def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if args:
            self.Name = args
        BaseCrudEntity.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        pass
```

I try to use a true django approach with super() call and so on but seems that it is not working here but I still don'know why.